# scale html into image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to develop an editor to write text, the output is html and the print it on a postcard.

I am developing a preview to check how the render will be before print. For example attached my postcard layout

[image]

As this is real postcard I have all my style in cm not in px (I know they is an easy conversion) but this is not the main issue.

Let say than the writable content of my postcard is 6 x 9 cm and the full size is 11 x 16 cm

At the moment I have everything in html, no background image but this is horrible on mobile because too big, I have to set some overflow and this is not user-friendly.

First I had the idea create a preview using a canvas and then generating an image which will scale automatically but it do not seems that canvas text do not accept html.

The other solution would be to use the scale transform in css taking the ration between the real template image size and the actual template image size then adjusting it using javascript. This could work but not very clean

Let me know if you see other alternatives

Comment: As it's HTML already, I wonder if you could do this mostly with CSS, so that as many measurements as possible use proportional units (%, vw, rem, etc) which then scale to whichever overall size is needed.

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand is you want to style your page to print it in postcard.
This can be done through css:

In your CSS file
you can define your print related styles as below.

```
@Media Print 
{
//your print related styles goes here
}
```

Follow the print in the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media